# Sending Text Messages (SMS) through Custom Keyboard Extension

Tags: swift3, keyboard, keyboard-events, uikeyboard, custom-keyboard

I'm new in the iOS development. 
Now I'm trying to develop a custom keyboard extension by using Swift 3.
I wonder how I could send a Text Messages (SMS) through my custom keyboard extension.
I have tried to do it in a basic application by using:

```
func sendMessage(){
    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        controller.body = "Input Body Here"
        controller.recipients = ["+1234567890"]
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch (result.rawValue) {
    case MessageComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Message was cancelled")
        break
    case MessageComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
        print("Message failed")
        break
    case MessageComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
        print("Message was sent")
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have tried that code and it is run smoothly in my testing device. Then now I want to implement those function on my new custom keyboard extension. Those code seems could not be implemented in the custom keyboard extension since the application extension couldn't present view controller.

Is there anyway to send Text Messages (SMS) through Custom Keyboard Extension?